# How to statistically compare two independent differences?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, effect-size

Three methods A, B and C are used to measure a continuous variable x for each subject in a study. There are two types of subjects in the study: type1 and type2.

**Difference between type**

xA1 - xA2  (difference in means of type1 and type2 as measured by method A)

xB1 - xB2

xC1 - xC2

**Difference between method**

xA - xB (difference in means between the measurements by A and B)

xB - xC

xC - xA

Now, how to statistically compare the difference between type and difference between method?

Bonus question: How to check if the method choice affects the group difference and also quantify it?

***One toy example*** would be an experiment where weights of subjects (male and female) are measured using three different scales. How to statistically compare inter-scale difference with the inter-gender difference?

One approach I am thinking is explained here -> [Statistical comparison of 2 independent Cohen's ds](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77269/statistical-comparison-of-2-independent-cohens-ds)
But both differences explained in the link are type1 - type2 kind and I am not sure if it is applicable to compare method1 - method2 vs. type1 - type2 differences. Also, I am wondering if there is an alternative way of comparing without calculating Cohen's d.

Comment: What do YOU think? Also if this is homework please add the `self-study` tag and have a look [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Please see the edited question.

Comment: What is your rationale choosing the approach you linked above? The type of analysis will also depend on what [scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement) your outcome variable is measured. Statistical tests also come with [assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_assumption) which have to be considered as well. You see given your information it's not really possible to give a better answer.

Comment: Let's assume your outcome was measured on the interval scale and you only have 2 methods (`A` and `B`) and no differentiation between `types`. Which statistical test would you choose? Why did you tag `t-test` in your question? Maybe this could be a starting point? From there you could add the third method (`C`) and also add additional types (`type1`, `type2`) and work yourself up to an analysis of variance for instance including [post-hoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_analysis) analysis.